# Lenovo YOGA Tablet 2 851F

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen, lenovo-laptop

I have [this tablet](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/tablets/lenovo/yoga-tablet-series/yoga-tablet-2-win-8/), and the story with it is very strange. First when I got it I had Win8.1 which I tried to upgrade to Win10. But it failed, because when after 60% it told me to chose language, my touchscreen won't work, keyboard or mouse, that I connected, won't work too. I am stuck at this step.

I have also tried to make bootable windows8.1 and windows10 usb drive, but touchscreen does not respond and I can't do anything.

So maybe is there a way I fix this. Maybe there is a way I can make bootable usb drive which installs touchscreen drivers for tablets?

Please help, as I am trying to fix this for two days with no results.

Comment: What article did you follow with upgrading? https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht103896

Comment: Just upgraded through Win8.1. After I failed, I also tried resetting through recovery, but it did not help

Comment: Did you update the bios? http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds101918

Comment: No. Can I do it without having Windows installed? Will it help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution was just to connect mouse to tablet BEFORE you start tablet. Then it sees the mouse and you will be able to finish setup.